# run bash script when ERROR spotted in logs in nxlog

Tags: nxlog

I am trying to run a script every time an error is found in logs

```
<Extension _exec>
    Module  xm_exec
</Extension>

<Input in>
    Module  im_file
    File    "/home/rafal/gitprojects/mst-sender/hub.cloudradar-error.log"
        <Exec>
        if $raw_event =~ /(\S+)\ (.+) \[ERROR (.+)/
        {
                exec_async("/bin/sh", "/home/rafal/gitprojects/mst-sender/run.sh");
        }

        </Exec>
</Input>
```

From their documentation it looks like it should exec async if regex matches but I am seeing only the following log 
 *WARNING not starting unused module in*
and the script is not executed. 
I don't need to output it, only run that script.

[**UPDATE**]added route

```
<Output out1>
    Module  om_null
</Output>

<Route 1>
    # Basic route
    Path    in => out1
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't need to output it, only run that script.

You need to.
What you can do is to create a route with `om_null` so that the output is discarded.

Comment: Yeah I got it working, that helped and there a small typo in my code, thanks